# Show that $\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}+ \frac{b}{c+a}}+ \sqrt{\frac{b}{c+a}+ \frac{c}{a+b}} + \sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}+ \frac{a}{b+c}} \ge 3.$

Tags: a.m.-g.m.-inequality

Suppose that $a,b,c>0$, show that
$$\sqrt{\frac{a}{b+c}+ \frac{b}{c+a}}+ \sqrt{\frac{b}{c+a}+ \frac{c}{a+b}} 
+ \sqrt{\frac{c}{a+b}+ \frac{a}{b+c}} \ge 3.$$

Appreciate any advice!

Comment: Maybe Cauchy-Shwartz?

Comment: @Chessplayer Yes, it may be useful, but I have no idea how to apply it to this case right now.